# StructureMap: Missing requested Instance property

Tags: c#, structuremap

I have a number of `INotificationProcessor`s.  For `BackorderCancelledEmailProcessor` I want it to print some stuff instead of sending it through the normal channel.  So I have a `PrintDispatcher`, but it errors, complaining that it can't resolve the `printLocation`, even though I have it configured.

Relevant setup:

```
 x.ForConcreteType<PrintDispatcher>()
   .Configure
   .Ctor<string>("printLocation")
   .Is(Settings.Default.Printer);


x.ForConcreteType<BackorderCancelledEmailProcessor>()
   .Configure
   .Ctor<INotificationDispatcher>("notificationDispatcher")
   .Is<PrintDispatcher>();
```

Constructors:

The `BackorderCancelledEmailProcessor` takes a number of arguments in the constructor, one of which is the notificationDispatcher.  Everything else is mapped (and this works without switching that).  The constructor for the other is:

```
public PrintDispatcher(string printLocation)
```

Error:

```
Build Error on Instance '{GUID}' (Configured Instance of BackorderCancelledEmailProcessor)
  for PluginType BackorderCancelledEmailProcessor

StructureMap.StructureMapException: StructureMap Exception Code: 205
Missing requested Instance property "printLocation" for InstanceKey "{Different GUID}"
  -Stack Trace-
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you are on the right way. My mapping in this casses is

```
x.For<INotificationDispatcher>()
 .Use<PrintDispatcher>()
 .Ctor<string>()
    .Is(Settings.Default.Printer);
;
```

So, whenever there is need for `INotificationDispatcher`, configured `PrintDispatcher` is returned